# The structure of the website is messed up

Tags: web, github, caching

I built a website on Azure and uploaded it to GitHub. [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlSlZ.png). After making a few changes, the structure of the website dispersed. [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My7q8.png)

Deleting the cache on Safari, Firefox, Chrome or Opera fixes the problem but, how may I delete the cache in GitHub or how can I fix this problem within GitHub? I checked forums, tried different ways but they never worked for my case. I used the command below but I guess this is not the way to fix it,

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git add . 
git commit -m 'git cache cleared'   
git push
```

[This](https://laszlorevesz.com/) is the website. I would be very happy if someone is able to help.